# React Native Stripe problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe payment into React Native application and I'm using code for reference that worked on React js project but I can't seem to get it working here. I'm still newbie so any help would be really appreciated.

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import axios from "axios"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'

const CARD_OPTIONS = {
    iconStyle: "solid",
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: "#c4f0ff",
            
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: "Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif",
            fontSize: "16px",
            fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
            ":-webkit-autofill": { color: "#fce883" },
            "::placeholder": { color: "#87bbfd" }
        },
        invalid: {
            iconColor: "#ffc7ee",
            color: "#ffc7ee"
        }
    }
}

export default function PaymentForm() {
    const [success, setSuccess ] = useState(false)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        
        const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        })
    

    if(!error) {
        try {
            const {id} = paymentMethod
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/payment", {
                amount: 1000,
                id
            })

            if(response.data.success) {
                console.log("successful payment")
                setSuccess(true)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error", error)
        }
    }else {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

    return (
        <>
        
        {!success ? 
        
            <View>
                <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS}/>
                <Button 
                    title="Pay"
                    onPress={handleSubmit} >
                </Button>
                <Text>Hello1</Text>
            </View>
            
        
        :
        <View>
            <Text>Purchase successful</Text>
        </View>
        }
            
        </>
    )
}
```

The Error I'm getting:

> View config getter callback for component 'div' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

And from experimenting I noticed that when commenting out

```
<CardElement />
```

it got rid of error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this use of the `CardElement` is not possible in React Native without something to act as a bridge to the native components.

In a [recent issue](https://dev.to/stripe/try-the-new-vs-code-extension-tiered-and-metered-billing-in-checkout-o1i) of the Stripe Dev newsletter, there is [a form](https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/b1a1053eaac7496eb0ae7892ebd68973) to share details of your integration and express interest in hearing more about Stripe's work with React Native. I strongly suggest filling that out to explain what you're working on!